# Windows OS not showing up in dual boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I've had Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot capability on my Dell for over 2 years, and then today I turned on my laptop and the Windows option has disappeared. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it detected when you run os-prober from grub? Maybe there was an update and it didn't detect Windows because it couldn't mount the partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup